# SpecJMS and HornetQ

Tags: java, jms, hornetq

I have seen one [post](http://hornetq.blogspot.com/2011/07/82-million-messages-second-with-specjms.html) about hornetQ. In that they have mentioned about specJMS. I wanted to know that how I can inegrate SpecJMS with HornetQ. I wanted to make test for that. I have tried and also installed SpecJMS 2008 Set-up and also Run it but wondering to make test of hornetQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get a license on spec.org

Notice that SpecJMS and SpecJ are different things...

Once you download specJMS (with the proper license from spec.org), you will have to setup destinations and configure the clients.

running a small test for your own is not very complex, however ramping up and follow the rules is something that can be very time consuming.

I can help you with specific issues when you hit them. But overall you just have to follow the spec.org instructions.

Comment: So, it means I have to configure my hornetQ consumer and producer in configuration of SpecJSM and then run it.

Comment: Configuring HornetQ for SpecJMS will mean:

I - Add the proper classpatch
II - Create the destinations accordingly to your currently push level. (there's a term for that on the SpecJMS manual, I really forgot the real term).


You have also to properly optimize your VM, disks.. etc. We have provided a lot of information on the hornetq.blogpost.com blog about it.